# How to display a html input using JavaScript : .html(' < input type="text" />')

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to show an input html code using JS when i select an option, this is my html code :

```html
<select id="mystuff">
       <option value="" disabled selected>Chercher selon :</option>
       <option value="Concessionnaire" >Concessionnaire</option>
       <option value="date" >Date entrée client</option>
       <option value="nom_client" >Nom client</option>
       <option value="prenom_client" >Prénom client</option>
       <option value="telephone" >Numéro de téléphone client</option>
       <option value="email" >E-mail</option>
       <option value="vehicule" >Véhicule</option>
       <option value="chassis" >Châssis</option>
       <option value="activite" >Activité</option>
</select>

<div id="msgbox"></div>
```

and this is my JavaScript code :

```js
$('#mystuff').change(function() {
       opt = $(this).val();
       if (opt=="concessionaires") {
       $('#msgbox').html('<select class="form-control" name="champ" id="viewSelector" required>

       <option value="concessionaires">Concessionnaire</option>
       <option value="date" >Date entrée client</option>
       <option value="nom_client" >Nom client</option>
       <option value="prenom_client" >Prénom client</option>
       <option value="telephone" >Numéro de téléphone client</option>
       <option value="email" >E-mail</option>
       <option value="vehicule" >Véhicule</option>
       <option value="chassis" >Châssis</option>
       <option value="activite" >Activité</option>
       </select> ');
       }else if (opt == "date") {
       $('#msgbox').html('<input name="valeur" type="date" class="form-control" laceholder="date" required>');
       }else if (opt == "chassis") {
       $('#msgbox').html('<input name="valeur" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="chassis" required>');
        }
    });
```

Tnx for your help !

Comment: Where is the script code?

Comment: You want to add an html code to an existing element? you can do that like adding into `innerHTML` of a `<div>` or something

Comment: what i want is when i select an option the javascript shows me the input according to that option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is mostly fine but you seem to have several syntax errors in it.

Check out a working version on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/03rtkv8v/1/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#mystuff').change(function() {
    opt = $(this).val();
    if (opt == "opt1") {
      $('#msgbox').html('<select class="form-control" name="champ" id="viewSelector" required><option value="concessionaires">Concessionnaire</option><option value="date">Date entrée client</option><option value="nom_client">Nom client</option><option value="prenom_client">Prénom client</option><option value="telephone">Numéro de téléphone client</option><option value="email">E-mail</option><option value="vehicule" >Véhicule</option><option value="chassis">Châssis</option><option value="activite" >Activité</option></select>');
    } else if (opt == "date") {
      $('#msgbox').html('<input name="valeur" type="date" class="form-control" laceholder="date" required>');
    } else if (opt == "chassis") {
      $('#msgbox').html('<input name="valeur" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="chassis" required>');
    }
  });
});
```

I had to delete several end-line characters and several spaces. I also wrapped it in a document.ready.

Comment: at the begining the input is hidden; and when i select an option the javascript shows me the input according to that option

Comment: I See. I have a lot of that on my site. Let me try again.

Comment: Actually looking at your additional javascript code it should be working fine. What is the issue you are having?

Comment: Updated my answer after debugging your code on jsfiddle.

Comment: indeed, i think my problem is the multiline html code, i'll try your solution thx

Answer (score 0):

I made a function (`inputNewHTML`) to show my comment. You can change the `innerHTML` of something and then it'll works just fine.

I made an HTML code which works as a live demo:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            *{
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
            #A, #B{
                width: 50%;
                height: 100%;
                float: left;
            }
            textarea{
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function inputNewHTML(newVar, target)
            {
                document.getElementById(target).innerHTML = newVar;
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="A">
            <textarea onchange="inputNewHTML(this.value, 'B')" onkeyup="inputNewHTML(this.value, 'B')"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div id="B">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I hope this is what you are looking for.